# Receiving Logger.ErrorHandler crash error after upgrading Elixir to 1.1.x

Tags: macos, homebrew, elixir

On Mac OSX 10.10.5, after doing the following to upgrade Elixir from v1.0.x to v1.1.x:

```
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade elixir
```

The following (edited for length) error occurs when attempting to run any app or started `iex`:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 27-Sep-2015::19:27:32 ===
** gen_event handler 'Elixir.Logger.ErrorHandler' crashed.
** Was installed in error_logger
** Last event was: <snip>
** When handler state == <snip>
** Reason == <snip>
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
```

Answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to occur when an Elixir app/binary is run with a different version of Erlang than Elixir was compiled with. In this case, the code was being run with Erlang 17 but was compiled with Erlang 18. You can read more in this [Github issue](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/3458).

It can be remedied by making sure the run & compile Erlang versions match. In my particular case on OSX I had multiple versions of Erlang installed (both via Homebrew & the [Erlang Solutions installer](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/erlang-otp/troubleshooting)).

**To start from a clean slate:**

```sh
# (Optional) To remove the Erlang Solutions installed Erlang
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/erlang/
# To remove all homebrew-managed versions of Elixir
brew uninstall --force elixir
# To remove all homebrew-managed versions of Erlang
brew uninstall --force erlang
```

**To do the reinstall:**

```sh
brew install erlang
brew install elixir
```